# How to detect different elements in list and create new lists from them (finding) with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, scripting

To send an e-mail element by element I need to first detect different elements in list and then create new lists from them.

Does anyone can help me about the problem below ?

**The list that I mentioned is also interrelated with another one.**

I have:

```py
list_I = [123, 453, 444, 555, 567, ...]

list_II = [A , A, B, C, B, ....]
```

What I hope to get is:

```py
New_list_I = [123, 453]

New_list_I_a = [A, A]
```

```
New_list_II = [444,567]

New_list_II_a = [B, B]
```

```py
New_list_III = [555]

New_list_III_a = [C]
```

Comment: `zip` and `groupby`?

Comment: And a sorting in the middle @DirtyBit

Comment: @yatu not the sorting, look for the desired output for `555`

Comment: @DirtyBit I tried with "zip", but couldn't handle with. I'll try to use "groupby"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplication of 2 separate which is interrelated with each other (PYTHON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240641/how-can-i-remove-duplication-of-2-separate-which-is-interrelated-with-each-other)

Comment: @DirtyBit not actually duplicate... It's just another step of my project :)

Comment: @GNDZHV Consider accepting an answer on your previously asked question?

Comment: @DirtyBit the previous one. I asked for removing duplication. Right now I kindly ask for finding items in a list and CREATE new list from them

Comment: @Thanthu do you think 2 question is similar

Comment: @GNDZHV Sure, if that was the reason, you can accept an answer posted on your every question which helps you solve the problem. That is what I asked, read here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @DirtyBit I accepted it. Sorry I'm new in website. Could you please remove your  "-1" on new question?

Comment: @GNDZHV I did not downvote, I can give you a complementary upvote though. Please see if any of the below posted answers help as well?

Comment: @DirtyBit I will try and reply to you in an hour my friend. I'm currently at job..  Thank you btw

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a dictionary from the two lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(list_2, list_1):
    d[k].append(v)

# defaultdict(list, {'A': [123, 453], 'B': [444, 567], 'C': [555]})
```

And then obtain the specified output from the dictionary using a list comprehension.

```
[[[k for _ in range(len(v))], v] for k,v in d.items()]
# [[['A', 'A'], [123, 453]], [['B', 'B'], [444, 567]], [['C'], [555]]]
```

---

Note that a nested list structure is much easier to handle and to work with than rather a series of lists created dynamically. Note that from this result you can select each resulting sublist using [Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a dict out of those two lists with a key,value and then sort on the basis of value:

```
list_I = [123, 453, 444, 555, 567]
list_II = ['A' , 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B']

res = dict(zip(list_I, list_II))
print(sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[(123, 'A'), (453, 'A'), (444, 'B'), (567, 'B'), (555, 'C')]
```